# To which side will it move?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque

Children pull the carousel with diverse forces (as in the picture below). In which direction will the carousel move?

Calculate the torque.

[image]

I have done the following:

The torque of the force that pulls the carousel to the right side is 200*1,2=240 Nm.

The torque of the force that pulls the carousel upwards is 180*1,1=198 Nm.

The torque of the force that pulls the carousel to the left side is 210*1,2=252 Nm.

The torque of the force that pulls the carousel downwards is 130*(0,6+0,6)+150*0,6=246 Nm.

Since 250 is the greatest torque, the carousel will move to the left side. Is this correct??

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: Define "to the left side". Given its birds eye view, the top half will move to the right bottom half to the left if moving clockwise.

Answer (score -1):

No. You have to take moments about the center.
Taking moments clockwise,

252Nm + 240Nm - 246Nm - 198Nm = 48Nm

Therefore it has a clockwise moment of 48Nm which implies it moves in the clockwise direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "moments" ?? Do have to add the torque of the forces??

Comment: Yes. You are dealing with a rotating object, so you must consider torques. The individual torques in the diagram can each induce a rotation. To find the overall direction of rotation, you must first find the net torque by summing the individual torques, adding and subtracting depending on whether the torque is applied in the clockwise or counterclockwise direction.

Comment: So since we have calculated the torques in the clockwise direction and the result is positive, the carusel will move to this direction and the torque that we are looking for is equal to $48Nm$, right?? @Rations

Comment: Yes. It will move with a clockwise torque with 40Nm.